# NAND Block "read cycles"

Tags: block

Nand blocks were "designed to fail" after an X amount of writes(10-100k). They are then flagged as broken.

Q: A write cycle is considered a signle electron write or a full wipe-then write ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The amount given is the max. guaranteed amount of "programming inclusive erasing" for all pages. Thus, full wipe-then write as you describe it. Some data sheets are so kind to include this explanation, some not.

Edit: The general term is P/E Cycles (Program/Erase Cycles)